# Using an alias with count and group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and have written code which counts the number of Subcategories in each Category of a database that I'm using (see below).

However, although the code works, it returns the results in an column with 'no column name.'

I tried to add an alias to the code eg `as NumberOfSubCats` at the end of each of the lines below (except the 'FROM' line) but it didn't work!

Does anyone know how I can add an alias to the unknown column name?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName), CategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY COUNT(SubCategoryName);
```

Comment: You should give your columnname an alias COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName) as CountSubCategoryNameDistinct and dont order by count. You can use your alias to Order by. So write order by CountSubCategoryNameDistinct instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName) NumberOfSubCats, CategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY NumberOfSubCats
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an alias in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName) as SubCategoryNameCount, CategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY COUNT(SubCategoryName);
```

or

```
SELECT SubCategoryNameCount = COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName) , CategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY COUNT(SubCategoryName);
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName) SubCategoryNameCount, CategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY COUNT(SubCategoryName);
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName) 'SubCategoryNameCount', CategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY COUNT(SubCategoryName);
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SubCategoryName) [SubCategoryNameCount], CategoryName
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY CategoryName
ORDER BY COUNT(SubCategoryName);
```

The output for all the queries above is:

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks! Tried the first solution and it worked!

Comment: @Mr2017 You're welcome. If you found this answer useful please consider accepting it (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer))